# Работа в фоновом режиме (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mobile-development

Подскажите как можно решить данный кейс для `iOS 9+`, `Android 4.4+` и `WP 8.1+`.

Программа раз в день должна проверять счёт пользователя и если он меньше 30 руб. то уведомлять.

Как реализовать уведомления на трех платформах я [разобрался](https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin).

А вот заставить программу работать постоянно (как сервис в Windows) не ясно и получиться ли это реализовать кроссплатформенно?

P.S. Пишу свое первое приложение для мобилок.

Comment: вам нужно копать в сторону "AlarmManager/AlarmService", который есть в андроиде и его эквиваленте на других платформах. Но похоже в ios подобного нет (удивительно), а значит в каждой платформе придется изворачиваться и меньше всего в андроид.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

То, что Вы хотите, называется Push Notification-ом. 
То, что Вы указали в примере - это локальное уведомление, по сути, c таймером на исполнение. Указали тайтл, текст, время, и вуаля, заданный текст показался в нужное время. 
В Вашем случае, такой вариант не подойдет просто потому, что счёт пользователя, как я понял - некое хранилище средств, лежащее извне, и для его проверки, понадобится исполнение кода приложения, а значит, приложение должно быть запущено. В случае с Пушем все проще, так как тут даже не нужна работа приложения, Вам нужен сервер который скажет, что нужно отправить уведомление.

Если я ошибаюсь, и его счёт сугубо виртуальная валюта, которая пополняется со временем - рассчитать время заполнения или растраты - не трудно, достаточно знать его потребление на момент изменения. Что касается первого варианта, если счета пользователя - некое подобие кошельков на Вашем сервере, то Вам понадобится только промежуточный сервис отправки подобных уведомлений, к примеру: FCM (Android), APNS (iOS), WNS (Windows). Ваш сервер через подобный сервис будет сам уведомлять пользователя о малом количестве средств.

Можете прочесть более подробно тут: [Основы успешной реализации push-уведомлений для мобильных приложений](https://habrahabr.ru/company/techmas/blog/262411/)

Comment: Впринципе я Вас понял, я пишу сервер который проверяет баланс пользователя и шлёт уведомление на тел. А на тел. в свою очередь реализую приём этих самых уведомлений которые будут работать всегда вне  зависимости от приложения, как час OC. Я рассматривал немного другой вариант есть некий сервис который запускается вместе с OC и каждый день выполняет POST запрос на сервер и в зависимости от результата показывает локальные уведомления. Возможна ли такая реализация?

Comment: К сожалению, Вашу идею на iOS реализовать нельзя. На ведре можно создать фоновый сервис, можете тут глянуть: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android

Answer (score 1):

https://xamdev.ru/background-task-xamarin/ 
Пишите отдельный код для каждой платформы, затем используете технологию отсюда https://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/12.3.php чтобы объединить все вместе